# IndexOutOfBoundsException with RecyclerView and ViewModel

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

I'm wondering why I can't get data from model.stat.observe() if I re-try to enter the app

when I debug app if I go outside and back to app, only model.stat.observe() isn't proceeded. so I can't get data and get error.
I don't know why. What should I fix?

```
model.allItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.setContentItem(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

model.stat.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.setStatItem(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
```

```
class BookViewModel(private val repository: BookRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val allItems:LiveData<Map<BookEntity,List<BookContentEntity>>> = repository.bookList.asLiveData()
    val stat:LiveData<Map<BookEntity,List<StatEntity>>> = repository.statList.asLiveData()

    fun insert(bookEntity: BookEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(bookEntity)
    }

}
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.jinproject.twomillustratedbook.Adapter.BookMainAdapter.onBindViewHolder(BookMainAdapter.kt:23)
        at com.jinproject.twomillustratedbook.Adapter.BookMainAdapter.onBindViewHolder(BookMainAdapter.kt:12)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
```

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: bookViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(content_items[position],stat_items[position])
    }
```

I can get data from content_items but not stat_items

Comment: It is very clearly. Your `content_items` or `stat_items` is empty

Comment: `@Query("select * from BookEntity inner join BookContentEntity on BookEntity.id = BookContentEntity.bookId ")
    fun getContent(): Flow<Map<BookEntity,List<BookContentEntity>>>

    @Query("select * from BookEntity inner join StatEntity on BookEntity.id = StatEntity.book_stat_Id ")
    fun getStat(): Flow<Map<BookEntity,List<StatEntity>>>`

they are not empty. I can get them first time I enter the app but if i go outside and back to app then I get error IndexOutOfBoundsException now.

Comment: So `content_items` or `stat_items` is empty when you go outside and back to app. That is the problem.

Comment: only stat_items is empty but I don't know why. so I am asking